# xaml resource errors when view open in editor

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a solution with multiple projects that has been building with no errors. Recently, I discovered that if I have a XAMview open in the editor, clean the solution then build it, I get a bunch of "Cannot find resource named 'Resource'. Resource names are case sensitive." errors. The 'Resource' that can't be found is referenced in a different view, not the view that I'm currently in. Any Static/Dynamic resources in the current view don't get the error. If I close the view and rebuild, the errors don't appear.

I've gone through and made sure all my namespace references are correct, the resource dictionary is in my app.xaml, all the keys are defined first in my styles, etc.

Any idea what could be causing this or how to solve it?

view with error:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <amp:AmpView DataContext="{Binding Path=Amp}" />
        <autoCal:AutoCalView DataContext="{Binding Path=AutoCal}"
                          Margin="5 0 0 0" />
    </StackPanel>
```

referenced view:

```
<Border Style="{StaticResource ContentBorderStyle}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left">
```

Resource:

```
<!--  Content container styles  -->
<Style x:Key="ContentBorderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ContentBackgroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ContentBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 5" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
</Style>
```

App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Src.Pl;component/Resources/Styles/StyleResources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: It generates those files on the build time, I don't see why is this a problem

Comment: @j0ey_wh The view above is in the project but not added to the shell. When I would get those errors with previous view, it would build fine but then would fail later when the view was added to the shell.